# drag a layout in android like in facebook for android app

Tags: android, facebook, drag-and-drop

i tried to implement Facebook like dragging by changing margins of a layout ,however those always leave behind trails even if i call invalidate on the view

Facebook for android /ios does it ,i wonder how they did it ,everywhere i see only images being dragged and dropped

i m trying to implement something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyhah.png) however it leaves behind trails in my app

```
package com.example.dragdemo;

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ParserError", "ParserError" })
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView x;
TouchExampleView tex;
Context ctx=MainActivity.this;

private float mPosX=0;
private float mPosY=0;

private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;

LinearLayout redLinear;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tex=new TouchExampleView(ctx);

    redLinear=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.newLinear);
    redLinear.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //Log.e("action is ", event.getAction()+"");

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(ctx, "comes in move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(((mPosX-(int) event.getX())>2002)||((mPosX-(int) event.getX())<2002)){

                    mPosX=(int) event.getX();
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    //rl.addRule(RelativeLayout., anchor)

                    rl.setMargins((int) event.getX(), 0, 0, 0);

                    redLinear.setLayoutParams(rl);
                    redLinear.invalidate();

                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: i thought adding 
if(((mPosX-(int) event.getX())>2002)||((mPosX-(int) event.getX())<2002)) would not leave trails however it had no effect on code whatsoever

Comment: Why not use one of the several _Sliding Menu_ libraries and generally make things easier for yourself?

Comment: i still want to know how its done , just want to know how to drag a ViewGroup

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy Feinstein's sliding menu library is an excellent implementation of a Facebook app style menu for Android. It doesn't have the trail issues you mention. You can find it here:

[SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) on github.

Comment: still can anyone tell me how to implement something like that